# How to disable / effectively remove Safari on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, firefox

I have installed my preferred browsers on iOS and, insofar as I was able to disabled Safari (and Siri, as various posts indicate that Safari and Siri are intertwined) and set Firefox as my preferred browser.  However I still find that if I open a website via an app, it typically (always?) opens in Safari.  Example: If there is a webpage link in an email client (fastmail or gmail) it opens in Safari.

I really really don't like Safari and if I could, I would delete it.  I understand that is not possible.  How can I at least make sure that it doesn't get used when I click on a link in an app?

Possibly useful details:

- iOS version: 17.4
- Location: Switzerland

Comment: How did you disable Safari? Did you set Firefox as default browser in Settings? Do your email clients have their own settings to define the web browser to open?

Comment: I browsed through settings and everywhere where I could see Safari being mentioned I deselected it.  I could not delete it.  https://developer.apple.com/support/browser-choice-screen/ says that there is a browser choice screen but it only applies to EU countries, not Switzerland.  Given that this is how hard it is to switch browsers I hope the DMA gets adopted everywhere! :-)

Comment: Does Firefox get opened if you tab on a link in Notes, or in a message you got?

Comment: I uninstalled Notes; in Fastmail, when I tap a link it is opened in Safari.  In Firefox, if I add a website to the home screen and then tap the website on the home screen, it opens in Safari, not Firefox.

Comment: PWAs (the websites on the homescreen) always open in Safari. In which apps does tapping a link open Firefox?

Comment: That is unfortunate.  Is there seriously no way to change that, so that PWAs open in Firefox?

Comment: Move to the EU …